# C++: Simple operator precedence issue or something else?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

If I have the following code:

```
long lSecondsSum = 8039;
double dNumDays = lSecondsSum / (24 * 3600);
```

I expect to get `0.093044`, but for some reason I am getting `dNumDays = 0.0000000000`.

However, if I write the code as follows:

```
long lSecondsSum = 8039;
double dNumDays = lSecondsSum/24;
dNumDays = dNumDays/3600;
```

then I get correct `dNumDays = 0.092777777777777778`.

How do I avoid all these floating point errors?

Comment: standard integer division error.

Comment: In simple terms, if you ever want a floating point answer, one of the inputs has to be fointing point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lSecondsSum is `long`, `8039/86400` will be `0`

If you convert `24 and 3600` to double, you will get correct result:

```
double dNumDays = lSecondsSum / (24 * 3600.0);
```

Or just:

```
double dNumDays = lSecondsSum / 24.0 / 3600.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first code snippet you are getting zero because all the math is being done as integers and then converted to double by the assignment. You want to to do all the math in double precision, e.g.

```
long lSecondsSum = 8039;
double dNumDays = lSecondsSum / (24.0 * 3600.0);
```

Your second code snippet works because the third line is done in double precision, however the second line is not and you may be expecting it to be, so watch out for that.

The reason for this working like it does is that if you do `long * long` or `long / long` then the result will be a `long`, not a `double`, even if you assign the resulting `long` to  a `double`, hence the result of your math was 0. This zero was then assigned to your `double`. However, `long / double` will be done in double precision and give you a `double` back, which is what you want. Essentially, be aware whether your calculations are being done as integer math or in double precision, otherwise you'll get caught out.